# Programmatically trigger rules action component

Tags: rules, actions

I have some problem in triggering an action component.
I tryed to call it from the module function and from the devel/php page.

This is my component settings
[image: component settings]

As you can see I have one node argument followed by 4 text arguments.
And i'm trying to call it with this code

```
$node = node_load( 981 );
$return = rules_invoke_event('rules_send_mail', 
    $node, 
    'mymail@gmail.com', 
    '123', 
    'nome', 
    'sss' );
print_r( $return );
```

Nothing is printed on the page.. not an array or a FALSE.
The action simply send and email to client_mail.

Can someone help me to understand why is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if its a rule action component than it should be called by

```
 rules_invoke_component('name', $other_parameters..);
```

while `rules_invoke_event()` is suppose to trigger an event on which you might have different rules to act on.

Comment: Just a quick note-- to invoke the component, you need to make sure to put `rules_` in front of the machine name for the `name`.

Comment: Mine is still failing to execute the action in `rules_invoke_component` because `rules_get_cache('comp_' . $name)` doesn't return a component object.  Help???